# How to pass process Id dynamically in activiti

Tags: activiti

I am using the same workflow for different use cases.so i want pass different process id for different use cases for the same workflow.How to i pass the process id dynamically to workflow based on some condition.Have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: this question is not clear at all.
what id are you refering?
do you have a process and you want to run it multiple times?

Comment: while developing the diagram finally we given the process id & process name for whole diagram  ok. That process Id.

Comment: didn't get much of what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

create a script execution listener on the start event of your process. do execution.getProcessInstanceId() and store it in a process variable by execution.setVariable("your_variable_name", value_from_the_method)